# Select object that has or doesn't have certain properties

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select, many-to-many

I have to extract the 'objects' from a Mysql database, according to the chosen 'properties'.
I would also like to be able to extract eg only 10 randomly among all those that satisfy the condition.

In my Mysql database I have these 3 tables:

Property

| id |
| --- |
| solid |
| spherical |
| edgy |

Object

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ball |
| 2 | dice |
| 3 | globe |

Property_Object

| obj | prop |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | solid |
| 1 | solid |
| 2 | edgy |

The Property-Object table is used to manage the many-to-many relationship between Property and Object.

I tried to get a table of this type, with NULL where the tag is missing, and then count for each name how many are the prop = 'solid' or prop = 'spherical' and how many prop = NULL, but without success:

| name | prop |
| --- | --- |
| ball | solid |
| ball | spherical |
| ball | NULL |
| dice | solid |
| dice | NULL |
| dice | edgy |

This is the select I tried to do, but I can't get it to work:

```
SELECT po.`obj`, po.`prop`
FROM `property` AS p
LEFT JOIN property_object AS po
ON p.`id` = po.`prop` AND (po.`prop`='solid' OR po.`prop`='spherical' OR po.`prop`='edgy')
ORDER BY po.`obj`;
```

**I managed to solve the problem:**

```
SELECT po.obj,
  COUNT(IF(p.id='solid' OR p.id='spherical',1,NULL)) AS c_own,
  COUNT(IF(p.id='edgy',1,NULL)) AS c_miss
FROM Property AS p, Property_Object AS po
WHERE po.prop = p.id
GROUP BY po.obj HAVING c_own=2 AND c_miss=0
```

'c_miss' must always be = 0.

'c_own' instead must be equal to the number of properties that the object must have.

Answer (score 0):

Such system are always tricky, especially when you need also not fitting rows and exclude other not fotting colmuns

But you can do

this basically makes a huge table with all wanted results and not wqanted as well and the where clause filters all objects out that don't fit

```
SELECT
  t1.name,po.prop
  FROM
(SELECT
p.id,o.id as obj_id, name
FROM 
Property p CROSS JOIN Object o) t1 LEFT JOIN Property_Object po ON po.`obj` = t1.obj_id AND po.prop = t1.id
WHERE t1.name IN ( SELECT DISTINCT o.name FROM Property_Object po INNER JOIN Object o ON o.id = po.obj)
```

| name | prop |
| --- | --- |
| ball | *null* |
| ball | spherical |
| ball | solid |
| dice | edgy |
| dice | *null* |
| dice | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZTrZPf8y)

Comment: I found a better way that I added to the question, which uses only one SELECT, but thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: That doesn,'t give the result you wanted , so better way is relative

Comment: I want to 'select object that has or doesn't have certain properties' and this I got.
What I initially tried to do was just a (wrong) way of approaching the problem and maybe I needed to clarify this better.